# How to manage a product attributes while adding/editing a product?

Tags: product, magento-2.1, module

I have created 2 attributes for my products, `attribute1` and `attribute2`, both are multi-select dropdowns.
What I wanted to achieve is that the second attribute values changes based on the options selected in the first attribute.

Suppose in attribute1 some `abc` is selected, in attribute2 some 'asa','asd','asd' these should be available. something like City and Area. If a particular city is selected, the area in that city should be listed there in 2nd dropdown.

I have a separate table for all the links between these attributes.

Layout File(`catalog_product_edit`);

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Myfle" 
                    name="module_block_adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_myfile"
                    template="Vendor_Module::module_product_dw.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Block File:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Myfile;
class Myfile extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [] )
    {
        $this->urlBuilder = $context->getUrlBuilder();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

**All are the files and folder structure is correct?** coz am getting a strange error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in ......./Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Myfile.php on line 7`

Note: PHP version is fine(5.6). And also Other blocks loaded without any problem.

Am stuck here.Please help how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to complete php tag for your block file as follows

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Myfile;
class Myfile extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [] )
    {
        $this->urlBuilder = $context->getUrlBuilder();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The closing ?> tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP. See coding standards [here](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)